# How to actively develop and debug single component feature in React library containing multiple component/features

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I wonder, what is "the right way" to actively develop a single React library feature/component with hiding all other features that are not important for the actively developed feature.

What are my requirements:

- do not wait for loading and rendering component which is not actively developed
- do not see a not actively developed component
- simply switch from active development of one component to another one

**"My way" how I do it:**

I am maintaining a React library that contains multiple components and features. This library is used in the final React application as a dependency. This project is actively developed and maintained for 5 few years.

When I am working on some feature request, I usually do not want to be disrupted with other features. I don't want to see them in the browser window, I don't want to wait for while they load and render. Hence, I prepared app.js file which usually renders all features (in a list, one component bellow another) from the library and when I am actively developing a single feature, I comment out all other features, like this:

app.js

```js
// my react redux application entry point

// Now I am actively developing feature Discover files,
// so every other feature (Dashboard, Reports, Sparklines) is commented out 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
<!--
// using html comments here,
// just to properly highlight comments in this code block
// here in stackoverflow
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <header style={{height: '650px', display: 'flex'}}>
                <DashboardContainer
                    {/* some dashboard props */}
                />
            </header>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Reports</h1>
            <header style={{height: '650px', display: 'flex'}}>
                <ReportsContainer
                    {/* some reports props */}
                />
            </header>
        </div>
-->
        <div>
            <h1>Discover files</h1>
            <header style={{height: '350px', display: 'flex'}}>
                <FilesContainer
                    {/* some files props */}
                />
            </header>
            <nav style={{height: '400px', display: 'flex'}}>
                <FilteringContainer
                    {/* some filter props */}
                />
            </nav>
        </div>
<!--        
        <div style={{width: '300px', marginBottom: '10px'}}>
            <h2>Sparklines:</h2>
            <SparklinesChart
                chartType={'bar'}
                data={[{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]}
            />
            <br />
            <SparklinesChart
                chartType={'bar'}
                data={[{x: -1, y: 25}, {x: 0, y: -5}]}
            />
        </div>
-->    
    </Provider>
);
```

Is this "the right way" with regards to the price/value of the problem solution?

I thought about using [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) as a solution, but I don't know if it is not an overkill solution  for my requirements (as it is probably necessary to prepare separate webpack config for building  storybook, configuring source watching properly, some boilerplate code for stories, ...).

Comment: In my opinion for such debugging Storybook is perfect. It isn't overkilled and I think (but I'm not sure) that everything that you need is out of the box right now.

edit: also you can check the idea of Kitchen Sink. Page of all components but without storybook. For example here: https://framework7.io/react/kitchen-sink.html

Comment: Thanks, I have some (but probably not enough) experience with Storybook two years ago and using it in a project was definitely not out of the box that time. But maybe it changed over these 2 years. Kitchen sink page is an interesting idea, I would think if it would be simpler to introduced such a solution than the storybook.